# Detecting a key press

Tags: c#, keyboard, keypress, slimdx

I am currently checking the keyboard state in my program:

```
SlimDX.DirectInput.KeyboardState keyboardState = keyboard.GetCurrentState();
```

And detecting key presses like this:

```
 if(keyboardState.IsPressed(SlimDX.DirectInput.Key.Q))...
```

I can't figure out how to detect ANY key press, rather than specific keys. I can't put my finger on it after trawling through the SlimDX API documentation. I'm probably missing something really simple no doubt.

Comment: Not the target, the platform. Windows I would guess? Why not use the normal forms call back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyboardState class has a `PressedKeys` read-only property which contains an `IList<Key>` of pressed keys.

You can check if this list is empty to know that nothing is pressed (`kbd.PressedKeys.Count == 0`).

If you want to respond to keyboard events and avoid the polling mode (explicit checks for keypresses) you should look to `SlimDX.RawInput` namespace and use the key press event handling, similar to WinForms.