# Detect ANY Key Press and Save

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard, key, detect

I know in Visual Studio you can detect a specific key press (EX: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990049/detecting-a-key-press)),
but is there a way to detect any key (`A-Z, 0-9, Shift, Ctrl, Alt, F1, F2` etc) and display it as a label (EX: `label1`). I intend to be able to use this while in any windows, not just the Visual Studio Program that i will be making. THANKS!

Comment: What do you mean by **Visual Studio Program**, and tell the difference compared to C#/Windows program?

Comment: I Edited the question !

Comment: Search for "low level keyboard hook" and WH_KEYBOARD_LL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make condition according to your need. Example Source [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" +
            e.KeyChar.ToString() + "' pressed.");

        switch (e.KeyChar)
        {
            case (char)49:
            case (char)52:
            case (char)55:
                MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" +
                    e.KeyChar.ToString() + "' consumed.");
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```